# More than one Bean of a class with different property values

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, annotations

I have to create four Beans of type JmsTemplate and i am passing the value of  "incomingqueue" reading from property file.
I want four different value of incomingqueue from four different placeholders in property file like in below mentioned code i have

```
@Value("${ibm.mq.incomingqueue}")
```

but i have three other place holders as well like

```
  @Value("${ibm.mq.incomingqueue1}") 
  @Value("${ibm.mq.incomingqueue2}") 
  @Value("${ibm.mq.incomingqueue3}")
```

and using those different properties i need 4 different beans.

is there any way i can have all those 4 placeholders' value in my property and inject in the bean ?

```
@Value("${ibm.mq.incomingqueue}")
    private String incomingqueue;

    @Bean
    public org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate provideJmsTemplate() 
throws JMSException {
        org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new 
org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate(provideUserCredentialsConnectionFactory
Adapter());
    jmsTemplate.setDefaultDestinationName(incomingqueue);
    return jmsTemplate;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need them in different environments(like queue1 for staging, queue2 for production, and so forth), then you'll have essentially 1 bean of JmsTemplate in application context per execution.

In this case, just use different profiles or if you're on Spring4+ `@Conditional` to load different beans. If you can decouple the configuration to supply just different queue names to different environments, then even better - you won't even need any conditional configuration there.

Now, in case you need 4 queues at once, the answer is different:

JMSTemplate bean has a singleton scope and it can work with only one queue at a time from what I see in your example (disclaimer, I haven't used JMSTemplate by myself). So you'll need 4 different beans. How would you differentiate between them when using dependency injection?

Here is an example of using Java Configuration:

```
    @SpringBootApplication
    public class SampleMicroserviceApplication {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
         SpringApplication.run(SampleMicroserviceApplication.class, args);
      }

      @Bean
      public Person john() {
         return new Person("John");
      }

      @Bean(name = "jack")
      public Person jack(){
         return new Person("Jack");
      }

      @Bean(initMethod = "init") // which person (jmsTemplate in your case to inject here??? 
      public Printer printer(Person p){
        return new Printer(p);
      }

      class Person {
        String name;

        public Person(String name) {
          this.name = name;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
          return "Person{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                '}';
         }
       }

       class Printer {
         private Person p;

         public Printer(Person p) {
           this.p = p;
         }

         public void init() {
           System.out.println(p.toString());
         }
       }
    }
```

Such a configuration will fail in Spring because it doesn't know what should be actually injected into the Printer class.

One way to solve it is using "@Qualifier" annotation:
Give a name to the person in the bean annotation like this:

```
@Bean(name = "john")
public Person john(){
    return new Person("John");
}

@Bean(name = "jack")
public Person jack(){
    return new Person("Jack");
}
```

And then in the beans specify what person exactly would you like to work with:

```
@Bean(initMethod = "init")
public Printer printer(@Qualifier("jack") Person p){
  return new Printer(p);
}
```

Now the context will start successfully. Of course in your example instead of persons you'll use different instances of JMS templates that have different queue names.